# RestKit 0.20.* tutorials that are actually up to date

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

Has anyone found tutorials for RestKits that are actually up to date? Not prerelease but something 0.20.* +. I was following along RestKits own tutorial that is suppose to be current and xcode is giving me a deprecated warning on one of their methods. 
https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Think I'm ready to jump oof the RestKit ship as if they aren't keeping their docs up to date that is a big warning sign for me. Also tried to build their latest examples from github and got a build error right away. Looks like a great project but someone who knows that library well needs to update the wiki and docs.